mDNS only on IPv6
Ubuntu Version: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
I'm having a weird issue with mDNS running on this host.
Using a discover tool on Macos I see the mDNS announcement from this host only on IPv6 and nothing on IPv4.
Reason for this troubleshooting was that I can't add "Yahka" a Homkit Bridge emulation anymore into Apple Homekit. I do see the bridge but when adding it times out.
My avahi.daemon status
adieball@s01:~$ sudo systemctl status avahi-daemon.service 
● avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-03-30 10:02:20 CET; 2 days ago
TriggeredBy: ○ avahi-daemon.socket
   Main PID: 3600 (avahi-daemon)
     Status: "avahi-daemon 0.8 starting up."
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 18917)
     Memory: 1.5M
        CPU: 3min 44.261s
     CGroup: /system.slice/avahi-daemon.service
             ├─3600 "avahi-daemon: running [s01.local]"
             └─3601 "avahi-daemon: chroot helper"

Mar 30 10:02:20 s01 avahi-daemon[3600]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s31f6.IPv4 with address 192.168.119.121.
Mar 30 10:02:20 s01 avahi-daemon[3600]: New relevant interface enp0s31f6.IPv4 for mDNS.
Mar 30 10:02:20 s01 avahi-daemon[3600]: Network interface enumeration completed.
Mar 30 10:02:20 s01 avahi-daemon[3600]: Registering new address record for fdd6:e4c8:2592:da48:6e4b:90ff:fe1c:8770 on enp0s31f6.*.
Mar 30 10:02:20 s01 avahi-daemon[3600]: Registering new address record for 192.168.119.121 on enp0s31f6.IPv4.
Mar 30 10:02:21 s01 avahi-daemon[3600]: Server startup complete. Host name is s01.local. Local service cookie is 1032175040.
Mar 30 10:02:41 s01 avahi-daemon[3600]: Files changed, reloading.
Mar 30 10:02:41 s01 avahi-daemon[3600]: No service file found in /etc/avahi/services.
Mar 30 10:02:50 s01 avahi-daemon[3600]: Files changed, reloading.
Mar 30 10:02:50 s01 avahi-daemon[3600]: No service file found in /etc/avahi/services.
adieball@s01:~$

According to this output it registeres on IPv4 and IPv6.
Checking with nmap:
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-04-01 13:16 CEST
Nmap scan report for s01.f0rd42.local (192.168.119.121)
Host is up (0.0000040s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
111/udp   open  rpcbind
5353/udp  open  zeroconf
10000/udp open  ndmp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.10 seconds
adieball@s01:~$ sudo nmap -sU localhost
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-04-01 13:16 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0000040s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT      STATE         SERVICE
111/udp   open          rpcbind
5353/udp  open|filtered zeroconf
10000/udp open          ndmp

What confuses me here if the "open|filtered" when doing the scan on localhost instead of it's IP Address. no "clue" what that means.
And why does it say "zeronconf" instead of "avahi"?
adieball@s01:~$ ss -l -p '( sport = :5353 )'
Netid                State                 Recv-Q                Send-Q                               Local Address:Port                                 Peer Address:Port                Process                
udp                  UNCONN                0                     0                                          0.0.0.0:mdns                                      0.0.0.0:*                                          
udp                  UNCONN                0                     0                                          0.0.0.0:mdns                                      0.0.0.0:*                                          
udp                  UNCONN                0                     0                                          0.0.0.0:mdns                                      0.0.0.0:*                                          
udp                  UNCONN                0                     0                                          0.0.0.0:mdns                                      0.0.0.0:*                                          
udp                  UNCONN                0                     0                                             [::]:mdns                                         [::]:*                                          
udp                  UNCONN                0                     0                                             [::]:mdns                                         [::]:*           

avahi-browse delivers:
adieball@s01:~$ avahi-browse -v _hap._tcp
Server version: avahi 0.8; Host name: s01.local
E Ifce Prot Name                                          Type                 Domain
+ enp0s31f6 IPv6 HomekitServer 6A42                            _hap._tcp            local
+ enp0s31f6 IPv6 HomePodSensor 381340                          _hap._tcp            local
+ enp0s31f6 IPv6 HomePodSensor 418146                          _hap._tcp            local
+ enp0s31f6 IPv6 HomePodSensor 969802                          _hap._tcp            local
+ enp0s31f6 IPv6 HomePodSensor 870291                          _hap._tcp            local
+ enp0s31f6 IPv6 HomePodSensor 627075                          _hap._tcp            local
+ enp0s31f6 IPv6 Philips Hue HomeKit                           _hap._tcp            local
+ enp0s31f6 IPv6 Basestation 5GP18C7TA13E6                     _hap._tcp            local
+ enp0s31f6 IPv4 HomekitServer 6A42                            _hap._tcp            local
+ enp0s31f6 IPv4 Basestation 5GP18C7TA13E6                     _hap._tcp            local
+ enp0s31f6 IPv4 HomePodSensor 627075                          _hap._tcp            local
+ enp0s31f6 IPv4 Homebridge 42AF 5A20                          _hap._tcp            local
: Cache exhausted
: All for now

Also fine as far as I can tell. BTW: Service in Question here is "HomekitServer 6A42"
result of the discovery from a different Device (MacOS runing on same network)

When trying to add the HomekitServer" to Homekit on ios (smae network) I do see the device as available but when I try to add it, it runs forever trying to add and ends with "not available". Interrestingly enough:
During this add process the name changes to "Bridge" in iOS instead of "HomekitServer"
Note: the Ubuntu and the appleTV running as the active bridge are both connected by ethernet on the same network
any help for additional troubleshooting are more than welcome.
